# Reference path for service account key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am referring to the next article [what is "serviceAccountKey.json" referring to in the Firebase device-to-device notifications tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874398/what-is-serviceaccountkey-json-referring-to-in-the-firebase-device-to-device-n/47626010#47626010)

There is one statement written in the index.js file

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
```

I would like to know what would be the path here when writing the script in the google cloud function web interface.

Do I have to upload the json file on a bucket and then give the bucket reference path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your serviceAccountKey.json in the same folder as your `index.json`. Then when you deploy to Cloud Functions, both the code and the key file will be uploaded and you can refer to the JSON from the code with:

```
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
```

Note that you may want to consider using the [Admin SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/) to send messages these days. This SDK didn't exist when I wrote blog post, but makes the code for sending messages simpler (at the cost of using an extra SDK).

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, the suggestion helped me to upload the script. As you had rightly mentioned about using Admin SDK, i did few changes to the blog script but i had to comment out the last statement that was calling the function itself to keep listening "listenForNotificationRequests();". With that removed, is there any way that i can keep the function running after the script is uploaded. - Thanks